# Is there any "Internet Kill Switch" feature in TOR Browser Bundle?

Tags: tor

At times a VPN drops connection and leaks traffic. Some VPNs have "Internet Kill Switch" to stop traffic automatically when this happens. Does TOR browser bundle also have any such feature by default ?

Answer (score 3):

The TOR browser bundle does not even route your whole internet traffic through TOR by default. It only routes the traffic of the bundled TOR web browser through TOR. Other applications which access the internet are not affected.

The TOR software works as a local proxy server. The <strike>Firefox</strike> Tor Browser is configured to use this proxy server by default. Other applications which use http(s) are not and must be configured manually to use 127.0.0.1 as a proxy. For applications which don't use http(s) or don't support setting proxy settings, [there is a guide on the tor wiki how to get these to use TOR](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO).

Should TOR stop working for some reason, any applications which use it as a proxy will no longer be able to load any websites. Other applications will not be affected because they didn't use TOR in the first place.